# How to make a sidebar in orchard that displays child menu items?

Tags: orchardcms

I am using the orchard CMS. I have 3 pages that have child elements on my navigation bar. I would like to make those pages show a sidebar that displays their children as another navigation inside the page e.g. "about/overview".

What would be the best way to go around doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate menus for the submenus. Let's say your "Main Menu" looks like this:

```
- Home
- About
  - Overview
  - History
  - Team
- Contact
```

You can create a separate "About" menu, and display it on an "About" widget layer in your sidebar zone. The new menu would just contain your "About" page children:

```
- Overview
- History
- Team
```

Adding a new menu can be done in admin under **Navigation** > **Add a new menu**.

Then you can add your new menu to your sidebar widget by going to **Widgets**. You'll want to make sure the widget is added to a widget layer that is specific to your "About" pages. So, you'll probably want to **Add a New Layer** that has the specific url layer rule so that it only shows up on /about/* pages. [More info on widget layers can be found in Orchard's documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Managing-widgets/#AddingaLayer).

Once you've added this new widget layer, you can add a **Menu Widget** to your sidebar zone. Just make sure the widget's "For Menu" field is set to your new "About" menu.